# Change property of multiple divs at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function which changes the width for seven divs. Right now it looks like this.

```
 document.getElementById('monday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('tuesday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('wednesday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('thursday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('friday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('saturday7').style.width = "76";
 document.getElementById('sunday7').style.width = "76";
```

This works flawlessly but I need to repeat similar code like the one above like 20 times.
So I have the following questions.

1. How do I change all the seven div widths at once? I mean something similar to this:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('monday7, tuesday7').style.width = "76";
   ```

   (Which didn't work).
2. Will this speed up the loading time, having one row like the one above compared to   having seven rows of code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you even try: `document.querySelectorAll('#monday7, #tuesday7').style.width = "76";`?

Comment: I don't know about querySelectorAll(), but if it's taking CSS selectors and those are ID, then you need '#monday7, #tuesday7'.  Further, it probably returns a collection of some kind, so you'll need an iterator of some kind.  As to speed, no, it won't speed it up -- but it'll be easier to maintain.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#monday7, #tuesday7').style.width = "76";

Did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give them all a class then do

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAME");
for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.width = "76";
}
```

elements is an array of all of the elements then you just loop through it and set them all. It requires minor changes to the HTML but will save you lots of space in the JS.

I dont know about loading time though might be slightly slower or around the same.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also makes this fairly simple. I'd suggest adding a class first though so all your elements can be accessed with one selector. So it would look like:

```
<div class="widthChange" id="monday7"></div>
<div class="widthChange" id="tuesday7"></div>
...
```

Then your jQuery would look like:

```
$('.widthChange').css('width', '76px');
```

Concise.